# Problema com texto acentuado JSON - Android + Retrofit

Tags: android, string, acentuação, retrofit

Estou consumindo dados de um webservice que retorna uma lista com objetos JSON, dessa forma:

```
[{"idPDV":3062,"nomeFantasia":"SEBASTIÃO  JOSÉ DOS SANTOS","endereco":"RUA MANCHE CATAN DAVID, 130","bairro":"VIDA NOVA","CEP":"79017164","latitude":"-20.382218","longitude":"-54.569492"}]
```

Alguns desses caras possuem acentuação no texto e acessando a URL pelo navegador eles vem todos acentuados corretamente na resposta da requisição. Porém quando faço a requisição no Android a resposta em JSON traz os caracteres acentuados substituidos por interrogações, de forma que tentar converter pra UTF-8 ou ISO-8859-1 no java também não deu certo. Fica dessa forma:

```
[{idPDV=3062, nomeFantasia=SEBASTI�O  JOS� DOS SANTOS, endereco=RUA MANCHE CATAN DAVID, 130, bairro=VIDA NOVA, CEP='79017164, latitude='-20.382218, longitude='-54.569492'}]
```

Esse é o codigo onde estou recuperando os dados:

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://minhaurl")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

PdvsService service = retrofit.create(PdvsService.class);
Call<List<PontoDeVenda>> call = service.allPdvs();

call.enqueue(new Callback<List<PontoDeVenda>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<PontoDeVenda>> call, Response<List<PontoDeVenda>> response) {

        for (PontoDeVenda pdv : response.body()) {
            Log.d("PDV", pdv.toString());
        }

        PdvArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new PdvArrayAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_lista_pdv, response.body());
            arrayAdapter.clear();
            lstPdvs.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            setOffLoading();

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<PontoDeVenda>> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("Erro", t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Existe alguma solução externa ou da propria lib retrofit que eu possa usar pra resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido utilizando a classe Interceptor da lib okHttp. A classe possui um método intercept() com o qual é possível manipular a resposta da requisição, alterando o MediaType pra configuração correta. Segue solução final:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
okHttpBuilder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {

@Override
public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(request);

    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json; 
    charset=iso-8859-1");
    ResponseBody modifiedBody = ResponseBody.create(mediaType, 
    response.body().bytes());
    okhttp3.Response modifiedResponse = response.newBuilder()
            .body(modifiedBody)
            .build();

    return modifiedResponse;
    }
});

retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://minhaurl")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(okHttpBuilder.build())
    .build();
```